# How to determine if two given vectors are complementary

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $U = (1, 4)^T$ and $V =(4, -1)^T$, I can tell that these two vectors are orthogonal because their dot product is $0$. But I'm not sure how to tell if they are complements to each other.

Any explanations in regards to this and how to tell if two vectors are complements would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The matlab notation [x,y]' isn't standard for vectors; it's normally written $(x,y)^T$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the complement is related to subspaces and not members/vectors.

The subspaces in question here are (This is the definition of orthogonal complement):
 $$B^{\bot}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \cdot y=0 \text{ for all } y \in B\}=span\{U\}=A$$ 
$$A^{\bot}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \cdot y=0 \text{ for all } y \in A\}=span\{V\}=B$$

So yes, these are orthogonal complements of each other.